# React Native and Firebase: My component is re-rendering on an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React Native and Firebase to build a chat app. The issue I am having is that my React component is rerendering in an infinite loop. I access the screen using a `StackNavigator` and am able to hit the back button in order to unmount this component to stop the infinite rerenderings. My code is below. Can someone help me figure out how to prevent the infinite rerendering?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore';

import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'


const Conversation = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const chatId = props.chatId;
  const userId = props.userId;
  const otherPerson = props.other;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const d = Date.now();

  firebase.firestore().collection("chatMessages").doc("chatMessages").collection(chatId).get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    console.log("snapshot");
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      const keys = Object.keys(data);

      let arr = keys.map((item) => {
        const messageId = item;
        const text = snapshot[messageId].text;
        const createdAt = snapshot[messageId].timestamp;

        const obj = {
          _id: messageId,
          text: text,
          createdAt: createdAt
        };

        return obj;
      });
      setMessages(previousArr => GiftedChat.append(previousArr, arr));
    }

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error : ", error);
  });

  firebase.firestore().collection("chatMessages").doc("chatMessages").collection(chatId)
  .where("otherPerson", "==", otherPerson)
  .onSnapshot((updatedSnapshot) => {

    let arr2 = [];
    updatedSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      arr2.push(doc.data());
    });
    setMessages(previousArr => GiftedChat.append(previousArr, arr2));
  });


  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={newMessage => onSend(newMessage)}
      animated={ true }
      user={{
        _id: userId,
        name: "Jane Doe",
        avatar: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/79.jpg"
      }}
    />
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: "80%",
    marginVertical: 8
  },
  view: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "100%",
    marginVertical: 50
  }
});

export default Conversation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling firebase functions inside render, which updates state causing render, which calls those functions again, which updates state causing render as so on. Move all of the side effects to `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.firestore().collection("chatMessages") // and so on...

  // all of the firebase queries here
}, [/* dependencies */])
```